# How to stop RenVM wrapper greeting?

Tags: terminal, command-line, rvm

Anytime I create a project through terminal, whether it be vue,react,angular -- anything -- I get this long greeting message on the renvm wrapper anytime I cd into a folder. It's super annoying and clutters up my terminal. Anyone know how to turn it of??

Here's the message

```
cd backend 
Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12 (latest) (c) 2009-2020 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin

# Wrapper

Show/regenerate wrappers.

NOTE: This command delegates to 'gem wrapper' => <https://github.com/rvm/gem-wrappers>

## Usage

Show paths and generated wrappers:

    rvm wrapper show


Show path to generated wrapper:

    rvm wrapper show executable_name

Where `executable_name` is something like `ruby` or `rake`.


It is also possible to generate a wrapper for external scripts that require ruby:

    rvm wrapper /full/path/to/script

Where `/full/path/to/script` is full path to existing script


Wrappers are generated automatically, but it is possible to rerun the process:

    rvm wrapper regenerate


Documentation:

    rvm wrapper [help]

For additional documentation please visit https://rvm.io

usage: 'rvm alias [action] [alias_name] [ruby_string]'
```

Comment: Same here. The prompt shows every time I `cd` in a Ruby project, it's super annoying.

Comment: I ended up factory reseting my computer for several different reasons but I reinstalled rvm and i'm no longer getting the message. Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up factory reseting my computer for several different reasons but I reinstalled rvm and I'm no longer getting the message. I'm not sure what the exact reason is but I believe that uninstalling and reinstalling rvm will fix the problem as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -x ~/.rvm/hooks/after_use_textmate`